# Accuracy computation with clustering in 3x3 matrix

Tags: clustering, accuracy, confusion-matrix

I have three true class, A, B, C in my dataset. and I got 3 clusters (0, 1, 2) from the clustering algorithm. They are not supposed to belong to the same class. 
For E.g. cluster 1 can belong to class C and cluster 2 can class A. I have the following confusion matrix. How should I calculate the accuracy here where it is not obvious, which class belongs to which cluster? Please help.

```
  0   1    2 
A 64  0   36
B 0   92   8
c 0  100   0
```

Answer (score 1):

The cluster (0,1,2) to label (A,B,C) mapping will be based on the one that maximizes your overall accuracy. In the case of the given confusion matrix the ideal mapping will be 0 --> A, 1 --> C, 2 --> B. So the confusion matrix will look like

```
  0      1       2
A 64     0      36
C 0      100    0
B 0      92     8
```

It is trivial to observe from your confusion matrix that your clustering algorithm is unable to properly distinguish between points of label B and C.

The overall accuracy is the sum of diagonals divided by the sum of all the values: $ 172/300 = 57.33 $ .

Answer (score 1):

Don't apply *classification* measures to clustering.

Instead, use **cluster evaluation measures** such as the adjusted Rand index (ARI) and normalized mutual information (NMI).

These measures are designed to *not* require rows and columns to be the same - they even can deal with different numbers of rows and columns.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: See the definition of the two measures I have here. They are well documented.